# Print application version using terminal

Tags: command-line, versions

Just out of curiosity, Is there any terminal command that prints out the version number of any application that is installed? For example, the version number of wine?

Comment: do you want to get the version number of the debian package installed?

Comment: `apt-cache policy wine | grep 'Installed:'`

Comment: `dpkg-query -W -f='${Version}\n' wine`